# Finding similar looking items from a dataframe using python

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe

A Python beginner.

I have a list of 20,000 products with its description. My task is to find all products which contain the the item which looks like this '00320047S01' or '02201179S02'.

[The list of products with highlighted products numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwT2b.jpg)

I tried out this

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:..\Desktop\Book1.xlsx') # Read the excel file
```

`df1['A'] = df1['A'].astype(str).str.lower()  # To lower case the data`

```
new = df1['A'][df1['A'].str.contains(r'00[0-9]{6}S0[0-9]{2}',regex=True)].tolist() # trying out regex  

[] #output
```

Where am i going wrong ?

P.S - All the items do not have a product number as in the picture attached.

Comment: How should we know how many product IDs you want to search for or what pattern the IDs follow?

Comment: i need all the products that hv a similar id

Comment: Please define "similar". You did not answer either of my questions. Also, please at least take the time to write out your responses properly and professionally.

Comment: similar in the sense '00320047S01'. Any product that has an ID similar to this one should come out as an output.

Comment: So, two leading zeros, followed by two non-zero digits, two more zeros, an "S" and two more digits? One of the highlighted IDs do not follow this pattern at all, which was the basis of my question... can you clarify please?

Comment: It can start with any number until S ie 8 numbers and then two more numbers after it

Comment: @coldspeed what was wrong with code?

Comment: Nothing was wrong with it. I ran it and it worked fine. The mistake was likely from your end. I just didn't feel it was worth the effort to continue this discussion based on my experience getting helpful information out of you which has been a steep uphill task thus far...

Comment: okay. Anyways thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pattern `r'00\d+S0\d+` or `r'00\d{6}S\d{2}'`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['00320047S01', '00201179S02', "Hello World"]})
print( df[df['A'].str.contains(r'00\d+S0\d+',regex=True)] )
```

**Output:**

```
             A
0  00320047S01
1  00201179S02
```